# docker-compose // piwik // error during run

Tags: docker, piwik, docker-compose

I try to switch all my app to docker.

**The configuration:**

I used nginx as server. With docker i will use it as proxy:

```
# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

Docker version:

```
# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:30:23 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:30:23 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

# docker-compose -version
docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35
```

**The install:**

To install piwik, i use the file suggest here:
[indiehosters/piwik](https://github.com/indiehosters/piwik/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

But i made some change because i would like:
- i would like to use a custom db so i configure an additional user and a password.
- i would like to use different containers of mysql by app so i change db to piwik_db (i am not sure it's a good practice)
- i would like to get a phpmyadmin access but i don't understand to make it work with the point 2. So i remove the config part.

So my docker compose fil looks like this:

```
piwik_db:
  image: mysql
  volumes:
    - ./mysql/runtime:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: P@ssR00t
    MYSQL_DATABASE: analytics
    MYSQL_USER: admin
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: P@ssUser
app:
  image: piwik
  links:
    - piwik_db:mysql
  volumes:
    - ./config:/var/www/html/config
    - ./ssmtp.conf:/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
    - ./revaliases:/etc/ssmtp/revaliases
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    - ./etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
  links:
    - app
  volumes_from:
    - app
  ports:
    - "8000:443"
cron:
  image: piwik
  links:
    - piwik_db:mysql
  volumes_from:
    - app
  entrypoint: |
    bash -c 'bash -s <<EOF
    trap "break;exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
    while /bin/true; do
      su -s "/bin/bash" -c "/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/console core:archive" www-data
      sleep 3600
    done
    EOF'
```

**The result:**

When i run `docker-compose up`, it finish with an error:

```
ERROR: for web  rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: could not synchronise with container process: not a directory"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 63, in main
AttributeError: 'ProjectError' object has no attribute 'msg'
docker-compose returned -1
```

When i test which containers was installed, i get

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f0388c2a89d3        piwik               "bash -c 'bash -s <<E"   About a minute ago   Up 59 seconds       9000/tcp            htdocs_cron_1
ef5d6c8c6e74        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.sh"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   3306/tcp            htdocs_piwik_db_1
```

**Why i get the error?**
**How to achieve the install?**
**How to make the app always running?**

Thank you in advance for any help.

---

Ps: I still use my nginx config in site-available:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name  piwik.domain.com;
        # Redirige le HTTP vers le HTTPS #
        return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {

        ##
        # config SSL
        ##

        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/piwik.domain.com.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/piwik.domain.com.com/privkey.pem;
        keepalive_timeout    70;
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

        server_name piwik.domain.com.com;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/piwik.domain.com.com/htdocs;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Logs
        access_log /var/log/analytics.access_log;
        error_log /var/log/analytics.error_log;

        # Default location settings
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                charset utf-8;
                client_max_body_size 20M;
        }

        # Images and static content is treated different
        location ~* ^.+.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot|otf)$ {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                expires 360d;
                access_log off;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny  all;
        }

        location ~ /(libraries|setup/frames|setup/libs) {
                deny all;
                return 404;
        }

        # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        location ~* \.php$ {
                # Prevent Zero-day exploit
                try_files $uri =404;
                #
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
                if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                        return 404;
                }
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        # Redirect server error pages to the static page
        error_page   403  /403.html;
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        # Exclude from the logs to avoid bloating when it's not available
        include drop.conf;

}
```

Comment: Just hit this too - the actual exception is a docker-compose bug really, it's excepting when trying to log the 'real' error that would help us. For me this has started happening without updating docker, and without updating the yaml or anything, which is really odd. Did you find a fix/workaround?

Comment: Not until now. Maybe i will try without docker-compose to test.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was because in compose file it was trying to mount files and not folders, changing it solved the issue